# Add new values to dataframe when multiple match with apply()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame df as below

```
d = {'letter_num' :['Nr. 1', 'Nr. 2', 'Nr. 3', 'Nr. 3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

   letter_num
0         Nr. 1
1         Nr. 2
2         Nr. 3
3         Nr. 3

letters = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['letter_num'])
```

I want to add the following dictionary's key and values as new columns to the above data frame on the condition that the (digits in the) keys match the existing (digit) values in the letter_num column in the df.

```
labels = {'[1]': 'budget', '[2]': 'budget', '[3 a]': 'expensive', '[3 b]': 'sport'}


def apply_and_concat(dataframe, field, func, column_names):
    return pd.concat((
        dataframe,
        dataframe[field].apply(
            lambda cell: pd.Series(func(cell), index=column_names))), axis=1)

def matcher(k):
    for i,j in labels.items():
      num =  re.search('(\d+)', i).group()
      if num in k.split(' '): 
        return i,j

apply_and_concat(df, 'letter_num', matcher, ['letters','content'])
```

The above code gives me an output as below:

```
 letter_num letters content
0   Nr. 1   [1]     budget
1   Nr. 2   [2]     budget
2   Nr. 3   [3 a]   expensive
3   Nr. 3   [3 a]   expensive


Expected Output:

 letter_num letters content
0   Nr. 1   [1]     budget
1   Nr. 2   [2]     budget
2   Nr. 3   [3 a]   expensive
3   Nr. 3   [3 b]   sport
```

Can somebody please help me out?

Comment: what's your input dataframe and expected output?

Comment: @baccandr I edited the post for better clarity. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a bit different approach - idea is create new `DataFrame` by `labels`, get numbers to new `Series` by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and mainly add counter of them by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

In this solutions are join together by [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) and set to index in both, so last is possible use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
d = {'letter_num' :['Nr. 1', 'Nr. 2', 'Nr. 3', 'Nr. 3']}

letters = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['letter_num'])

labels = {'[1]': 'budget', '[2]': 'budget', '[3 a]': 'expensive', '[3 b]': 'sport'}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({(k, v) for k, v in labels.items()}, columns=['letters','content'])
num = df1['letters'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df1.index = df1.groupby(num).cumcount().astype(str).str.cat(num, sep='|')
print (df1)
    letters    content
0|3   [3 a]  expensive
0|2     [2]     budget
0|1     [1]     budget
1|3   [3 b]      sport
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

num = df['letter_num'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df.index = df.groupby(num).cumcount().astype(str).str.cat(num, sep='|')
print (df)

    letter_num
0|1      Nr. 1
0|2      Nr. 2
0|3      Nr. 3
1|3      Nr. 3
```

---

```
df = df.join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  letter_num letters    content
0      Nr. 1     [1]     budget
1      Nr. 2     [2]     budget
2      Nr. 3   [3 a]  expensive
3      Nr. 3   [3 b]      sport
```

Or create new columns and use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
d = {'letter_num' :['Nr. 1', 'Nr. 2', 'Nr. 3', 'Nr. 3']}

letters = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['letter_num'])

labels = {'[1]': 'budget', '[2]': 'budget', '[3 a]': 'expensive', '[3 b]': 'sport'}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({(k, v) for k, v in labels.items()}, columns=['letters','content'])
df1['num'] = df1['letters'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('num').cumcount()
print (df1)
  letters    content num  g
0   [3 a]  expensive   3  0
1     [2]     budget   2  0
2     [1]     budget   1  0
3   [3 b]      sport   3  1
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#print (df)

df['num'] = df['letter_num'].str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
df['g'] = df.groupby('num').cumcount()
print (df)
  letter_num num  g
0      Nr. 1   1  0
1      Nr. 2   2  0
2      Nr. 3   3  0
3      Nr. 3   3  1
```

---

```
df = df.merge(df1, on=['num','g'], how='left')
print (df)
  letter_num num  g letters    content
0      Nr. 1   1  0     [1]     budget
1      Nr. 2   2  0     [2]     budget
2      Nr. 3   3  0   [3 a]  expensive
3      Nr. 3   3  1   [3 b]      sport

df = df.drop(['num','g'], axis=1)
print (df)
  letter_num letters    content
0      Nr. 1     [1]     budget
1      Nr. 2     [2]     budget
2      Nr. 3   [3 a]  expensive
3      Nr. 3   [3 b]      sport
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My output was slightly different than yours i.e. the order of 3a and 3b - 3b comes first and 3a later. It was was okay back then but now I realised I need to maintain the order. Do you think you can help me figure it out?

Comment: @minalee - One question - what is your python and pandas versions?

Comment: I am running my code on Google Colab, I think the latest Python version is 3.6.7? and pandas version is 0.25.3.

Comment: @minalee - hmmm, I ask because posible problem should be different python version, now I cannot simulate your problem :(

Comment: No problem! Thanks! :)